# Speed of Windows' ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() + RevertToSelf() vs Unix's seteuid() + setegid()

Tags: windows, security, winapi, unix

In Unix, when doing some action on behalf of some user, a system program usually calls seteuid(UID) (with accompanying setegid()) to switch to that user first, perform the action, and on finish switch back to superuser using seteuid(0). I time seteuid() and it's in the order of one to several microseconds (meaning, it's quite cheap relative to the action that needs to be done like manipulating files or running a CGI program).

I'm not familiar with Windows API. Do we do the same thing on Windows (but using ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() + RevertToSelf() API functions)? In general, how fast are these functions?

Comment: Those API calls merely change the token associated with the thread, probably copying a few bytes. It changes the thread token, so there is no lock. I wouldn't worry about it. Remember that *premature optimisation is the root of all evil* (Knuth).

Comment: If seteuid() is one to several microns, I wonder how long printf() is.  Maybe a full centimeter?  ;-)

Comment: @ixe013: Please don't misunderstand my intention. I was not trying to optimize things, I was merely wondering about the difference in security model. The thing I remember mostly about the difference between the two OS family is how the CreateProcess() WinAPI function is much more heavier than Unix's fork() (and also how they have notable differences). Thus, creating process is not as often done in Windows and using threads is more popular than in Unix.

Comment: This is actually a very good question, but maybe not just formed exactly the right way.  As you point out, fork() and CreateProcess() are very different, with CreateProcess() being much heavier than fork().  Hence, Windows programmers tend to use threads more, which are closer in performance to fork().  But in the end, I think @ixe013 is probably right: ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() is probably very fast, much faster than fork().

Comment: Thanks @StevenHaryanto, I think I got it now. I tried an answer, I hope it will help you, at least for book suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mostly the same, but there is one important difference to keep in mind : the Windows API you mentionned require a HANDLE to a valid token.

In other words, even running as SYSTEM (or any process that has SeTcbPrivilege), you need to impersonnate a ***logged on user***.

The user can be logged on many ways :

- Interactive with at a physical computer
- Through a Remote Desktop Session
- Pretty much any Microsoft network connections like file shares, name pipes, mailslots, RPC and all the others built on top.

Creating a process will make it inherit the current token in most cases.

It does not matter whether you used Kerberos, NTLM or maybe HTTP BASIC auth in IIS. It's all authenticated by Windows, so you get a token. On the other hand, an HTTP BASIC authentication in Tomcat will not give you a Windows token, so impersonation is out of reach.

Now with the tricky part.

When you think about it, a token is really just a memory structure with access control lists for authorisation (DACL) and auditing (SACL). It is created by an [Authentication Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (AP). It is the AP that creates the token. And somewhat like a PAM in Unix, an AP can be replaced by custom code.

As a matter of fact, an open source setuid Authentication Package exist. Folks who ported CVS to Windows NT did the work of writing an AP that [creates a token out of thin air](http://cvsnt.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.5.03.2151/setuid_8cpp-source.html), as long as your have the SeTcbPrivilege (root equivalent). I have never tried it, but it could give a token on the local machine for a user that is absent. The code is rather old (it will only create elevated tokens) but besides that, it LGTM. There is no authentication, no password or smart card involved, so a process running with that made up token will not be able to use it to authenticate to another computer.

To conclude :

- The general idea is the same
- If you play by the rules, you will only be able to impersonate a logged on user, regardless of the login procedure or location
- You can change that behavior, but it
- Impersonation is probably just as fast in Unix and Windows, as the inner workings are roughly similar. Chances are you will not notice the difference.

A suggestion : my copy of [Programming Windows Security](http://www.pluralsight.com/books/pws/default.htm) is all yellow from coffee, with post-it notes hanging out and torn pages. The best text ever on the subject, a must read if you want to understand Windows security.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Although much of the Windows jargon is still mumbo jumbo to me, I've gotten a rather clearer picture. So suppose you're writing a web-based file manager that allows a Windows user to manage her files through a browser, would ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() work here? You just need to pass the authentication information you receive from the user via web form to IIS? What if we want to allow a "manager" to edit other user's files, without him logging in as that user first? And can we use CreateProcess() to create a process running as any user we want?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the book. It's dated year 2000. Has Windows security changed much since then?

Comment: Everything in the book is still valid. You even see the building blocks of the missing pieces, like what came to be [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756986.aspx) and [Restricted Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379316(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: IIS can/will impersonate the user if you use a Windows based authentication (Kerberos, some HTTP basic and client-certificate scenario). I suggest you ask a new question when you get there.